# AutoLayout: NSInternalInconsistencyException with iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios11

App getting crashed with the following logs(P.F.A) and Its only getting crash in iOS 11.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException, Impossible to set
>   up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
>
> __120-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]_block_invoke_2

[image]

**Update**:-

Scenario:- I have a UIToolbar on the keyboard, The code for adding

The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0295540 V:[UIToolbar:0x10219f550]-(0)-[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderV‌​iew:0x10219fab0] (inactive)

```
#pragma mark  KeyBoard Related Function
-(void)createInputAccessoryView:(NSInteger )tagNumber
{
    inputAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    [inputAccessoryView setBackgroundColor:kKYBOARDCOLOR];
    [inputAccessoryView sizeToFit];
    [inputAccessoryView setHidden:NO];

    //Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons

    UIBarButtonItem *barSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                              target:nil
                                                                              action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                  target:self action:@selector(actnResignKeyboard)];
    NSArray *barItems;
    barItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barSpace,barBtnDone, nil];
    [inputAccessoryView setItems:barItems animated:YES];

}
```

Appearing and disappearing keyboard causes crash but when I remove UIToolbar, then every thing working fine.

**Note :- This code is working fine prior to iOS 11.**

Comment: can you determine which constraints (or at least which view) are causing this

Comment: This error occurs if you try to layout constraints for a view that is not yet added to view heirarchy.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ please have a look now

Comment: well, there is obviously something wrong with with the constraint based layout (autolayout) - can you share the code where you set up constraints?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0295540 V:[UIToolbar:0x10219f550]-(0)-[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x10219fab0]   (inactive)>

Comment: this is the crash log.. I am talking about your code where you set up layout

Comment: the complete code is written in the question and apart form it i haven,t write any code to add accessory view(UIToolbar) of UITextfiled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing the stacktrace to know which layout or view hierarchy causes this? Also try adding the views to the superview first and then apply the constraints